# Find Activity by name using reflection if the Activity is in a subpackage

Tags: java, android, reflection

I use this method to launch activity according their names:

```
   public void startAct(String activityName) {
            try {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getPackageName() + "."
                        + (activityName.trim()));

                Intent myActivity = new Intent(Home.this, clazz);
                startActivity(myActivity);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Home", "Error: " + e.getStackTrace());
            }
        }
```

this method works fine if all `Activity` are at the same package level of the activity where I have written this method
e.g. `com.myapp.uk`
.... if the Activity are in a subpackage eg `com.myapp.uk.group1` seems unable to start the `Activity`... I need a way to fix the method to works also if the Activity are in various others subpackages `com.myapp.uk.group1` `com.myapp.uk.group2` `com.myapp.uk.group3` etc.

Comment: When you call getPackageName() you are using your own package name, but you need that of the target Class.

Comment: exactly but I'm looking for a way to find the activity in packacge and its subpackage

Comment: If you know the subpackage just specify that.  If not, it's harder (in the general Java case apparently unsupported, but possibly on Android)

Comment: the problem is that there isn't only A subpackage but different subpackages and is unknows what is the respective subpackage of the activityName.... the reflection should check the activity in all package and subpackages

Comment: You might have better luck getting a list of Activities out of the package manger based on their manifest entries.